# How can I use approval workflow to reject changes of any existing list item?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, check-out, approval

I've been creating reusable workflow using **SharePoint Designer 2010**. You can see a screenshot of the workflow code by clicking on the below link.

[My custom approval Worfklow code image](http://i54.tinypic.com/igc6c6.jpg)

I tried different approches, like **check out current list item** and **check in item**, but the workflow gives an error like :

> "please make sure item has already been checked out".

All in all, I want to check approve status from the approval process, and depending on the status I want any change in existing list item saved in a list, if approved, simply mail to creator, if rejected, changed version of existing list item should be discarded.

Comment: Use event receivers. See the blog post *[SharePoint 2010: Send Notification on Item Approved/Rejected (when Content Approval Status is changed)](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/10/sharepoint-2010-content-approval-events.html)*.

Comment: "My custom approval Workflow code image" is not directing to image. please provide correct url

Comment: The image link is (effectively) broken.